# Trust of Team Member

Tags: work-environment

I had joined the new org and I have this guy who is reporting to me, who is very hardworking and talented and very open, I had started trusting him and planned to promote him in next 6 months. But last week we had a holiday and on same day we had a conference call, it was not mandatory to join, hence I attended all by alone and answered the queries.

But this guy is claiming he has attended and resolved which is telling blatant lie in front of me.

I thought after giving hints he will accept the truth, but still this guy is adamant.

I have not told him i also attended the call and did not find this guy in call other side.

Now please guide me here the next steps.

Comment: @bishu JoeStrazzere is right.  Tell him you were there. Then play it by ear from the moment you say it. You are his superior, so it'd be interesting if he called you a liar. Actually, since he was there, I,m sure that he'll have NO trouble writing up the minutes of the meeting i.e. the time meeting started, the time it ended, who attended, who excused themselves in the middle of the meeting, what was discussed, what was resolved, what the action items are. And since he was there, you'd want to know who he talked to and about what. Right?

Comment: Does this confirm a suspicion that this person is dishonest and/or affect your decision to promote him? The question needs to be more specific which should also include more details.

Comment: @bishu, I have same problem with one guy in my team. But unless we prove we can not take action on team member. If we are wrong those actions will fire back upon us.

Answer (score 1):

Was this a web conference where you can see the names of everyone there, or a phone conference where you just didn't hear him contribute to the conversation?  Maybe he was technically there but not mentally present?

I'd agree that the best course of action is to to tell him that you were there and didn't see any sign of his presence and see how he reacts.
If he admits his lie and seems seriously repentant the relationship might be salvageable.  Or it is barely possible that he is mistaken in some way, and when he finds out he will be apologetic.

But if he gets angry and defensive you may not want to put this guy in a situation where you have to depend on his integrity or manageability.

How a person reacts to their own mistakes is far more important than what mistakes they make.